# Copula with one property

Tags: copula

We know that a multivariate distribution $F(x,y)$ can be expressed as copula via $C(F_1(x),F_2(y))$ with $F_1,F_2$ being the marginal distribution.

I am trying to construct a multivariate distribution with one property: $F(x,x)=F_1(x)$ for all $x$. Such a property can be rewritten in terms of copula via equation $C(F_1(x),F_2(x))=F_1(x)$. The relation between $F_1 $ and $F_2$ is that $F_1>F_2$. (I actually know their functional forms and can manually compare them)

I believe the usual copula provided in wikipedia do not work since my property seems to be asymmetric. Then
I tried to use the following theorem to construct asymmetric copulas but could not construct the desired copula:
[image]

I am just wondering whether it is possible to recover the copula with only property  $C(F_1(x),F_2(x))=F_1(x)$? If so, any idea to proceed? If not, what other properties do I need?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your copula is necessarily the upper bound: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)#Fr%C3%A9chet%E2%80%93Hoeffding_copula_bounds.  It implies the two random variables are comonotone (whence the distribution is degenerate).  Is this really what you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you mind explain more on your first 2 sentences? I did not see why the 2 random variables are comonotone (comonotonicity seems to require equality for any pair of $(x,y)$, but my property only has diagonal $(x,x)$)
and why the copula is the upper bound?

Comment: Hi, do you the following argument is valid? Fréchet–Hoeffding Theorem states $C(F_1(x),F_2(x)) \leq \min \{F_1(x),F_2(x)\}$. And my $F_1$ and $F_2$ have the property $F_1>F_2$ (I can actually compute the marginal distribution and compare them). So contradiction happens and actually $F_1=F_2$.

Comment: I don't see the contradiction.  Instead, the relationships $$\Pr(X_1\le x)=F_1(x)=C(F_1(x),F_2(x))=\Pr(X_1\le x,X_2\le x)=\Pr(X_2\le x\mid X_1\le x)\Pr(X_1\le x)$$ imply $\Pr(X_2\le x\mid X_1\le x) = 1$ for all $x$ in the support of $F_1$ and you can go on from there.

Comment: The contradiction is that $C(F_1(x),F_2(x)) \leq \min \{F_1(x),F_2(x)\}$ but $C(F_1(x),F_2(x)) =F_1(x)>F_2(x)$. (I can actually compute the marginal distribution and compare them)

Comment: @whuber Do you mind illustrate your hint in more detailed words or just in the answer area? I can not follow your idea. Thanks!